# Does DOS run Crysis?

Tags: ms-dos, gaming

There certainly exist machines that can run both DOS and Crysis, but both at the same time? I had something like the [HX DOS extender](https://www.japheth.de/HX.html) in mind and [mesa3d](https://www.mesa3d.org/) can be compiled for DOS and Windows. There seem to be some [misunderstandings](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/issues/15) as regards DOS, it was not limited to 640k. There are videos of [386 machines running Quake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2zsV-kXMIk&ab_channel=MichaelHuth), but that was an earlier game. [DOSBOX](https://www.dosbox.com/) itself can run under DOS, so running [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) under dos and xp inside that may be possible.

Comment: How do you envision this? One CPU running DOS and the other Windows XP with a game? Or simply Dosbox not crashing under Windows?

Comment: @Theras just plain (free)dos booting up on a powerful machine and running Crysis somehow.

Comment: "DOSBOX itself can run under DOS, so running qemu under dos and xp inside that may be possible" There's a large stretch there, the fact that DOSBOX runs on DOS (can't find a source for that though) doesn't mean you can run QEMU on DOS, as it is not a supported platform (and lacks the APIs necessary for standardized virtualization)

Comment: @kouta-kun that's necesary because new machines are so much faster than old ones. I think I saw this on hx extender page.

Comment: @kouta-kun it’s described on [the HX page](https://www.japheth.de/HX.html) — look for “Running QEMU with HX” and “Running DOSBox with HX”.

Comment: @StephenKitt and this probably means that you can run xp under dos, leaving only a suitable software d3d implementation that needs to be taken care of.

Comment: @user1095108 as I mention in my answer, that would be painfully slow. QEMU on top of DOS provides no access to the GPU (AFAIK), and is limited to a single CPU core.

Comment: @StephenKitt still, a video could be made of Crysis running under DOS. Hopefully, someone will post one on YouTube.

Comment: With enough effort, sure, it could be done. Though it’s effort so massive, I doubt anyone would be willing to expend it.

Comment: @user3840170 I remember a time when hx could not run qemu, but now it does. It may happen eventually.

Comment: “running qemu under dos and xp inside that may be possible” – you can also perform an obscure trick of installing XP under an ultra-lightweight ring-0 hypervisor providing full pass-through for all devices and executing guest code directly on the host CPU for maximum performance.

Comment: 1.8 frames per second is not a playable experience. It took a pentium to be fast enough for being fun.  later came 3D acceleration that helped a lot

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen We need to have a working solution to measure those 1.8 fps.

Comment: The quake video actually measures exactly this and shows the result at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Quake was originally written for DOS, so running it on a DOS computer isn’t particularly special — what’s unusual in the video you mention is the CPU and FPU being used (Quake was really a Pentium game). More recently, [Quake II has been ported to DOS too](http://dk.toastednet.org/Q2DOS/).

Crysis however relies on Direct3D, and even with HX you won’t be able to run that on DOS, at least not usably — while HX can run OpenGL programs, it does so without any acceleration, so even if you added a Direct3D-to-OpenGL translation layer, the result would be agonisingly slow (bear in mind that DOS and DOS programs run on a single core). Running QEMU on HX and Windows inside that would suffer from the same lack of acceleration.

Comment: Yeah, but there's emulation of d3d possible with the help of gl, I believe.

Comment: https://github.com/code-tom-code/Software_D3D9 , for example.

Comment: Yes, Wine does that too, and then you could use Mesa to provide OpenGL, which you mentioned in your question. But I suspect you’d need to put in a fair amount of work — is that in scope?

Comment: Why not? I'm not working on it though, just checking if a solution is already available. Crysis is a popular game.

Comment: Well, I’m not aware of a solution already being available.

Comment: I think I remember Quake not really running if you called it from DOS 6.  But that may have been coincidental with all my Pentiums running Windows 95 by the time it came out.  I'm pretty sure it didn't need DOS mode.  It's weird.

Comment: @davolfman I played it on a number of plain MS-DOS and Novell DOS systems, without Windows 95. It could even do multiplayer (with the appropriate network setup).

Comment: Quake did not run well on 486 machines so that really helped pentium sales.  386 sounds like a theoretical exercise.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, the video illustrates that — it runs, but too slowly to be playable.

Comment: @StephenKitt the frame rate of myst as I saw it described once.